# How to solve for $n$ variables from $n$ each containing a single unknown variable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve $n$ equations such that:
$$a_1(b_1-x_1) = a_2(b_2-x_2)=a_3(b_3-x_3)=\ldots=a_n(b_n-x_n)$$
such that 
$[x_1]+[x_2]+[x_3]+......+[x_n] = m.$

Here all $a,b$ and $m$ are positive integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use LaTeX to format your question properly as I did with the first line. Also, please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks @AhmadBazzi . I'll remember that next time.  I really couldn't think of anything in this case neither I could find something on MSE. Before this searching on MSE has always been helpful. I tried to separate them all using a new unknown constant but that adds another variable.

Comment: I don't need full solution. Just a hint in the right direction. Also I have to be able to solve this programmatically.

Comment: Write each $x_i$, $i\ne1$, in terms of $x_1$, then use the last equation.

Comment: Yeah sounds good. How can it be done programmatically? To me it seems like recursion is the only option.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "programmatically". If you're asking for tips on writing code, that's a question for a coding site, not for this math site. By the way, are you using $[x]$ for the greatest-integer function (also known as the floor-function)?